# Need to access same webservice in all controller with specific parameter ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

example like master view
just i need to access specific parameter in every view but there is only one service.

```
$scope.file=[
{num:"1",descript:"consumer",status:"closed",casedet:"cleared"},
{num:"2",descript:"literal",status:"open", casedet:"process"},
{num:"3",descript:"literal",status:"closed", casedet:"cleared"},
{num:"4",descript:"consumer",status:"open",casedet:"proess"}
];
```

in first view am accessing num, descript and status

button 1 display 1, consumer, closed

button 2 display 2, literal, open
.
.
.

```
<a class="button icon button-block button-calm icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle" ng-class="{'button-balanced': file.status == 'open', 'button-assertive': file.status == 'closed'}" href="#filedetails" ng-repeat="file in file | orderBy:'-status'" >File Ref No:{{file.num}}<br>
        Description:{{file.descript}}<br>
        Status:{{file.status}}</a><br>
```

i need to display in another view by clicking button 1 from data in num one array

num:1
descript:consumer
casedet:cleared

thanks in advance

Comment: do u want to..display the details in same state OR in new State..?like..u can show the data in Ionic Modal..in same state..!

Comment: by click to display in new page

Comment: [try this](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-9-passing-data-between-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using $stateParam and ui-sref.

First create one new state called 'app.filedetails'

Pass the num and other detail value with $state URL from current state 
like

```
<a class="button icon button-block button-calm icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright-circle" ng-class="{'button-balanced': file.status == 'open', 'button-assertive': file.status == 'closed'}" ng-repeat="file in file | orderBy:'-status'" ui-sref = "app.filedetails({num:file.num,descript:file.descript,status:file.status})"> File Ref No: {{file.num}} </a>
```

And read it from state : 'app.filedetails' controller like below,

```
$scope.file = [{
num: $stateParam.num,
descript: $stateParam.descript,
status:$stateParam.status}]
```

Comment: for this u need to declare state like this : .state('app.filedetails',{
url:'/filedetails/:num/:descript/:status',
}